# Methods for edge detection with non-equidistant samples

Tags: discrete-signals, edge-detection, time-series, nonuniform

This posting describes two methods of edge detection for wave analysis in a water pipe. I am not sure about advantaged and disadvantages. Therefore I want to evaluate the best method for this application. So please suggest new ones or judge the suggested.

**Situation:** There is a constant water flow through a pipe (horizontal - with constant diameter). Suddenly the pump stops and the resulting pressure drop travels along the pipe. There are several measurement points, which take a sample triggered by the sufficient value-change. Therefore the datapoints are not equally distributed in time.

**Aim:** I want to calculate the sound speed in the fluid from the velocity of this pressure wave. For this I need a method to detect the edges.

**Approach 1:** My first approach was to take the middle of this step which has a differential quotient above a certain treshold:

```
      if ( sign(treshold)*(y(count+1) - y(count))/(t(count+1) - t(count))   > sign(treshold)*treshold) then

            tCutOff(j) =  0.5*(tCut1(count+1) + tCut1(count));
```

[image: Edge Detection 2]

**Approach 2:** During some experiments, an advanced method came to my mind. It was motivated by the variation of the steepness in the first step of the edge. I alternatively tool the last few points before the detected step and some followers.

```
 precursor = [ t(count-5: count-1) ; y(count-5: count-1)]
 follower  = [ t(count+1 : count+2); y(count+1: count+2)]
```

Then I build the regression with the line parameters a and b each. The cutoff point is defined as the crossing of both regression lines:

```
    tCutOff(j)  = -(follow_b - pre_b)/(follow_a - pre_a);
```

With the second approach I got the following results.
[image: Edge Detection 3]

Comment: Did I choose the wrong forum?

Comment: I think about a now approach: 1) FIR LP filtering 2) numerical derivation 3) LP filtering of the derivative 4) `find(max(abs(derivate)))`. Any hints?